# Rails 3: Using a gem as my main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use the code of a gem as my main application code instead of just installing it with "bundle install".

How can I create an entire rails app based on a gem and using that gem as my app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Rails Engines](http://www.anup.info/2010/02/21/rails-30-mount-multiple-apps-as-engines/) instead I believe. If not, then can you explain your problem further?